# No gradients provided for any variable for custom loss function

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I have created a custom loss function in Keras as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
   cce = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()
   loss = cce(y_true, y_pred).numpy()

   epsilon = np.finfo(np.float32).eps
   confidence = np.clip(y_true.numpy(), epsilon, 1.-epsilon)
   sample_entropy = -1. * np.sum(np.multiply(confidence, np.log(confidence) / np.log(np.e)), axis=-1)
   entropy = np.mean(sample_entropy)
   penalty = 0.1 * -entropy
   
   return loss + penalty
```

When I use this custom loss function I'm getting the error message

> ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable

Somehow now gradients can be calculated. How needs the loss function be changed so that gradients can be calculated?

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow need `tensor` to store the dependency info to let gradients `flow` backwards, if you convert tensor to numpy array in loss function then you break this dependency thus no gradients provided for any variable, so you need change every `np` operation in loss function to corresponding `tf` or `backend` operation, e.g:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

cce = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()
epsilon = np.finfo(np.float32).eps

def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    loss = cce(y_true, y_pred)
    confidence = tf.clip_by_value(y_true, epsilon, 1.-epsilon)
    sample_entropy = -1. * tf.reduce_sum(tf.math.multiply(confidence, tf.math.log(confidence) / tf.math.log(np.e)), axis=-1)
    entropy = tf.reduce_mean(sample_entropy)
    penalty = 0.1 * -entropy
    return loss + penalty
```